# Dynamically replace ListView table cell with textField wicket

Tags: ajax, label, wicket, textfield

I have a listView which has a single column which needs to be editable only in certain cases. If the user needs to change the column, I want them to click a edit button for the row, then replace the label in the cell with a textField. When I call replace I can see the TextField is now in the place of the label, although it is never rendered. I have a AjaxLink to handle the event. I am using a container to repaint the listView. Here is my listview:

```
    parent = new WebMarkupContainer("emp-table-parent");

    parent.add(new AjaxLink<Object>(FIRST_NAME_HEADER_LINK) {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -1937727929649333407L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

            changeGlyphUpdateList(target, parent.get(FIRST_NAME_HEADER_LINK).get(FIRST_NAME_HEADER_ICON), 
                    parent.get(LAST_NAME_HEADER_LINK).get(LAST_NAME_HEADER_ICON),
                    parent.get(EMAIL_HEADER_LINK).get(EMAIL_HEADER_ICON), parent.get(ELIGIBILITY_CLASS_HEADER_LINK).get(ELIGIBILITY_CLASS_HEADER_ICON),
                    parent.get(EMPLOYER_HEADER_LINK).get(EMPLOYER_HEADER_ICON));

        }

    }.add(new Label("first-name-header-label", Model.of("First Name")), new WebComponent(FIRST_NAME_HEADER_ICON)),
            new AjaxLink<Object>(LAST_NAME_HEADER_LINK) {

                /**
                 * 
                 */
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -3438649095509412910L;

                @Override
                public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

                    changeGlyphUpdateList(target, parent.get(LAST_NAME_HEADER_LINK).get(LAST_NAME_HEADER_ICON), 
                            parent.get(FIRST_NAME_HEADER_LINK).get(FIRST_NAME_HEADER_ICON), 
                            parent.get(EMAIL_HEADER_LINK).get(EMAIL_HEADER_ICON), 
                            parent.get(ELIGIBILITY_CLASS_HEADER_LINK).get(ELIGIBILITY_CLASS_HEADER_ICON),
                            parent.get(EMPLOYER_HEADER_LINK).get(EMPLOYER_HEADER_ICON));

                }
    }.add(new Label("last-name-header-label", Model.of("Last Name")), new WebComponent(LAST_NAME_HEADER_ICON)),
            new AjaxLink<Object>(EMAIL_HEADER_LINK) {

                /**
                 * 
                 */
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 2890934302751793454L;

                @Override
                public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

                    changeGlyphUpdateList(target, parent.get(EMAIL_HEADER_LINK).get(EMAIL_HEADER_ICON), 
                            parent.get(LAST_NAME_HEADER_LINK).get(LAST_NAME_HEADER_ICON),
                            parent.get(FIRST_NAME_HEADER_LINK).get(FIRST_NAME_HEADER_ICON), 
                            parent.get(ELIGIBILITY_CLASS_HEADER_LINK).get(ELIGIBILITY_CLASS_HEADER_ICON),
                            parent.get(EMPLOYER_HEADER_LINK).get(EMPLOYER_HEADER_ICON));

                }

    }.add(new Label("email-header-label", Model.of("Email")), new WebComponent(EMAIL_HEADER_ICON)),
            new AjaxLink<Object>(ELIGIBILITY_CLASS_HEADER_LINK) {

                /**
                 * 
                 */
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -4022209586109961448L;

                @Override
                public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

                    changeGlyphUpdateList(target, parent.get(ELIGIBILITY_CLASS_HEADER_LINK).get(ELIGIBILITY_CLASS_HEADER_ICON), 
                            parent.get(EMAIL_HEADER_LINK).get(EMAIL_HEADER_ICON), 
                            parent.get(LAST_NAME_HEADER_LINK).get(LAST_NAME_HEADER_ICON),
                            parent.get(FIRST_NAME_HEADER_LINK).get(FIRST_NAME_HEADER_ICON), 
                            parent.get(EMPLOYER_HEADER_LINK).get(EMPLOYER_HEADER_ICON));

                }

    }.add(new Label("eligibility-class-header-label", Model.of("Elig. Class")), new WebComponent(ELIGIBILITY_CLASS_HEADER_ICON)),
            new AjaxLink<Object>(EMPLOYER_HEADER_LINK) {

                /**
                 * 
                 */
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -738777257301408437L;

                @Override
                public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

                    changeGlyphUpdateList(target, parent.get(EMPLOYER_HEADER_LINK).get(EMPLOYER_HEADER_ICON), 
                            parent.get(ELIGIBILITY_CLASS_HEADER_LINK).get(ELIGIBILITY_CLASS_HEADER_ICON), 
                            parent.get(EMAIL_HEADER_LINK).get(EMAIL_HEADER_ICON), 
                            parent.get(LAST_NAME_HEADER_LINK).get(LAST_NAME_HEADER_ICON),
                            parent.get(FIRST_NAME_HEADER_LINK).get(FIRST_NAME_HEADER_ICON));

                }

    }.add(new Label("employer-header-label", Model.of("Employer")), new WebComponent(EMPLOYER_HEADER_ICON)),
    new PageableListView<EmployeeSummaryPkt>("data", employeeSummaryModel.getObject(), 25) {

                /**
                 * 
                 */
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -1697070076764699904L;

                @Override
                protected void populateItem(final ListItem<EmployeeSummaryPkt> item) {

                    item.setDefaultModel(new CompoundPropertyModel<EmployeeSummaryPkt>(item.getModelObject()));

                    item.add(new Label("firstName"),
                             new Label("lastName"),
                             new Label("employeeEmail"),
                             new Link<Object>("eligibility-class-data-link") {

                                /**
                                 * 
                                 */
                                private static final long serialVersionUID = -3842291392813313171L;

                                @Override
                                public void onClick() {

                                    //LINK TO ELIGIBILITY CLASS OR MAYBE THE SECTION WITHIN THE EMP?

                                }
                    }.add(new Label("employeeEligibilityClassSummaryPkt.name")),
                             new Link<Object>("employer-data-link") {

                                /**
                                 * 
                                 */
                                private static final long serialVersionUID = 6809571267919974106L;

                                @Override
                                public void onClick() {

                                    getIndex().getHomePanel().setNewContent(new EmployerDetailPanel("panel-content", item.getModelObject().getEmployerSummaryPkt().getId()));

                                }

                    }.add(new Label("employerSummaryPkt.name")),
                             new Label("employeeDateOfBirth"),
                             new Label("employee-code", Model.of(item.getModelObject().getEmployeeName())).setOutputMarkupId(true),
                             new AjaxLink<Object>("edit-employee-link") {

                                /**
                                 * 
                                 */
                                private static final long serialVersionUID = 6061544430700059358L;

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

                                    logr.log(Level.FINER, "onClick for edit employee");

                                    logr.log(Level.FINER, "employee code pre: " + item.get("employee-code").getClass().getSimpleName());
                                    item.get("employee-code").replaceWith(new TextField<String>("employee-code", new Model<String>(item.getModelObject().getEmployeeName())).setOutputMarkupId(true));
                                    logr.log(Level.FINER, "employee code post: " + item.get("employee-code").getClass().getSimpleName());
                                    target.addChildren(parent, TextField.class);
                                    target.add(parent);
                                }
                    });
                }
```

As you can see, the label with the id "employee-code" is the label I wish to replace. Inside the AjaxLink onClick, you can see where I am getting the label and replacing it. Nothing is changing. Any direction or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The declaration for `parent` does not seem to be in the code snippet you posted?

Comment: Sorry about that. I edited above to add in the snippet for parent.

Answer (score 3):

A ListView recreates each if its items on each render, thus the altered listItem is thrown away immediately.

`ListView#setReuseItems(true)` should help.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. Hope this helps others with similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to svenmeier's answer could also be to add only the specific item that has been changed to the `AjaxRequestTarget`. That is, replace

```
target.addChildren(parent, TextField.class);
target.add(parent);
```

With

```
target.add(item.get("employee-code"))
```

Which would cause only the piece of markup that concerns the change to be re-rendered, as opposed to the entire table. If your table is big and contains a lot of elements, whose models involve complicated retrieval mechanisms rendering the entire table would be a much more laborious process, and hence re-rendering only the item would be a better solution.

Having said that, in your particular case svenmeier's solution is better, as otherwise if you implement my solution and later on re-render the entire table, the changes would be lost.

Comment: I agree, this is the method I have used in the past, yet it escaped me because I have sorting by column functionality built into this table, thus why I was adding the parent with the entire table. Thanks for the answer. I believe @svnemeier's answer will be more appropriate since if they sort, the textfield will then be replaced by the default label. Very good answer nonetheless.